# Meaning of cross product of real and complex part of a complex eigenvector

Tags: complex-numbers

Let's say we have a complex eigenvector (**v**) as a result of a natural frequency calculation of multi DoF system.
I'm wondering what kind of physical meaning has the cross product of Re(**v**) $\times$ Im(**v**).

Thank's for the answer in advance

Comment: Presumably you’re working in $\mathbb R^3$ (or perhaps $\mathbb R^2$) since you have a cross product at all to ask about. Think about the plane spanned by the real and imaginary parts of $\mathbf v$ and how it relates to the scaled rotation represented by the complex eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes indeed i forgot to add that i'm talking about $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1546104/265466. The real and imaginary parts of $\mathbf v$ span the plane of the (scaled) rotation, so in $\mathbb R^3$ their cross product defines the corresponding rotation axis. The length of this cross product is pretty much meaningless since you can scale an eigenvector arbitrarily.